# :hover property, when I will use group selector

Tags: html, css, hover

As you can see in this CSS code, I am using CSS group selector. When I use CSS group selector and :hover property, it's not working.

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    background: rgb(196, 152, 71);
    width: 375px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    color: rgb(2, 51, 2);
}

// **problem section**
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6:hover {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <h1>This is a h1 headig</h1>
     <h2>This is a h2 headig</h2>
     <h3>This is a h3 headig</h3>
     <h4>This is a h4 headig</h4>
     <h5>This is a h5 headig</h5>
     <h6>This is a h6 headig</h6>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write for all of them separately:

```
h1:hover,h2:hover,h3:hover,h4:hover,h5:hover,h6:hover {
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 rebeccapurple;
        }
```